# CMake Error at HW1_generated_student_func.cu

Tags: github, parallel-processing, cuda, google-colaboratory

I tried to do the homework assignments of udacity's famous **parallel programming**(cs344) course. I found a repository in github that using google colab platform did it. [udacity-cs344-colab](https://github.com/depctg/udacity-cs344-colab)

I tried to run that reposiotory in colab but I got errors.

When I run the cell

```
# make the cuda project
!make HW1
print("\n====== RESULT OF HW1 =======\n")
!bin/HW1 ../src/HW1/cinque_terre.gold
```

I get an error like this:

```
[ 20%] Building NVCC (Device) object HW1/CMakeFiles/HW1.dir/HW1_generated_student_func.cu.o
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_30'
CMake Error at HW1_generated_student_func.cu.o.cmake:222
```

Comment: CUDA 11.x will not allow builds that include [this line](https://github.com/depctg/udacity-cs344-colab/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt#L24).  So remove that line.  That is what is being indicated in the linked duplicate.

Comment: For example, after starting the first (HW1) notebook, in the very first cell, before the last line of that cell which is `!cmake ../src`, insert this line: `!sed -i '24d' ../src/CMakeLists.txt`  then execute that cell and proceed with the notebook.

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate and your edit removed the exact source of your problem, wich is trying to build for an unsupported GPU architecture

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobertCrovella, it worked for me.